# Proving that the kernel of a presheaf morphism is a subpresheaf

Tags: sheaf-theory

Let $F\to G$ a morphism between presheaves in $X$.

I'm trying to prove that $\ker_\varphi$ is a subpresheaf of $F$. The easy part is prove that $\ker_\varphi (U)\subset F(U)$ for every open sets of $X$ (I proved very easily).

However, I couldn't prove that the following diagram commutes:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\ker_\varphi(U) @>\text{inclusion}\;>> F(U) \\
@VVV @VVV\\
\ker_\varphi(V) @>>\text{inclusion}\;> F(V) \\
\end{CD}$$

I almost sure that I'm forgetting something really silly. 
If someone could help me, I would be very grateful.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Don't you define the left vertical arrow so that the diagram you showed commutes, then you show it is uniquely determined?

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld the vertical arrows are the restriction morphisms of the sheaf $\ker_\varphi$, but I don't know how to defined it.

Comment: You do a diagram chase. Let $x\in\ker(U)\subseteq F(U)$. Then, $(\varphi_V\circ\text{res}_{U,V})(x)=(\text{res}_{U,V}\circ\varphi_U)(x)=0$, so $y$, the restriction of $x$ in $F(V)$ is in the image of the inclusion at the bottom of the diagram.

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld $y$ is not a restriction of $x$ in $G(V)$, instead of $F(V)$?

Comment: user42912: No. (If we were in person I could make this obvious to you much faster.) Let $y=\text{res}_{U,V}(x)$. Then $\varphi_V(y)=0$ by the commutativity of the square with horizontals $\varphi_U,\varphi_V$. Thus, $y\in\ker\varphi_V$, which is the image of the inclusion on bottom.

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld I think it's better you write for example $\text{res}_{U,V}1$ for restrictions of $F$ and $\text{res}_{U,V}2$ for restrictions in $G$ to make a distinction between the two restrictions.

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld I understood what you meant, what I didn't understand it's why the restrictions in $F$ are the same of the restrictions in $G$.

Comment: user42912, here's what I will do: $\text{res}_{U,V}^F$ for the restriction map on $F$. Since $\varphi$ is a presheaf morphism (think natural transformation), $\varphi_V\circ\text{res}_{U,V}^F=\text{res}_{U,V}^G\circ\varphi_U$. Evaluate the RHS on $x$, etc.

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld What you said is correct, but why $\text{res}_{U,V}1\circ \text{upperinclusion}=y$? in order to commute the diagram?

Comment: What's your question? (Perhaps chat is better for this btw)

Comment: I didn't see a comment you wrote, sorry, I'm thinking.

Comment: It remains only one doubt, if $T$ is the morphism represented by the left vertical arrow, why $T(x)=y$?

Comment: user42912 It is the only way to define $T$ so that the square you drew in the question commutes. Intuitively, it is the restriction of the restriction map of $F$ to $\ker_\varphi$. You still have to check that it is a valid restriction and all that, but it all follows from the commutativity of that one square.

Comment: By the way, in this instance, it actually is not any harder to use the universal property of $\ker$ in the abelian category in which the objects $F(U),G(U)$, etc., reside. You can prove, in a half page or so (depending on how large you write :)), that for any abelian category $\mathcal A$ and any small category $X$, $\mathcal A^X$ is abelian without diagram chases.

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld This question doesn't seem so easy as I thought. Any way, thank you very much for trying to help me, I'm really grateful. I will think about this problem tomorrow.